# Would you recommend Amazon Web Services for a WordPress site or MediaTemple?

Tags: amazon-s3, hosting, amazon-web-services, mediatemple

Would you recommend Amazon Web Services for a WordPress site or should I stick with using MediaTemple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: it depends. How granular do you need to get with your WP install? If you need to govern every aspect of your install and maintenance from a console or "super user" perspective then it makes sense to take on a AWS. However, most WP users do just fine via the thorough management tools that WP provide and can work just fine on a host like MediaTemple (or others). You'll also need to consider costs. I think that even with a cheap mini instance and moderate transfer, AWS is going to run you $20 a month - most WP hosts are considerably less than this. In most cases, I'd say that you're better off staying with someone like MediaTemple rather than getting down & dirty with a WP server and install.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the level of info I was looking to know. AWS has some really neat bells and whistles and flexibility, but I don' think I'm ready to handle that level of responsibility now.

Comment: @Jim Beam - It's been a while since this question has been visited, but curious if you could speak to AWS's performance vs. the performance of a site on MT? If someone plans to scale a site up to include multiple members with lots of data (image files, video files, etc.) is there a benefit to using AWS or would MT work just fine? Also curious about site maintenance help - MT has people available to chat if you are having an issue. Does AWS have decent customer help?